# sip: Unable to find file "QtGui/QtGuimod.sip"

Tags: python, c++, pyqt4

When I try to create a Qt/C++ project for python code from [A More Complex C++ Example](ftp://ftp.lpp.polytechnique.fr/jeandet/keep/sync/sip/Using%20SIP%20%E2%80%94%20SIP%204.16.9%20Reference%20Guide.html)

in the step:

```
python configure.py
```

I got the error:

```
PS E:\data\CPython\sipPyQt4\sip> python.exe .\configure.py
sip: Unable to find file "QtGui/QtGuimod.sip"
Error: Unable to open
"E:\CPython\sipPyQt4\sip\hello.sbf"
```

I find QtGuimod.sip is in `...\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\sip\PyQt4\QtGui` dir.

Why build system cannot find it?

## Environment

- Windows10
- sip-4.19.17
- PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.7-Qt4.8.7-x64

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using linux.

Resolution:

- Download PyQt4;
- In your folder PyQt, copy the folder call sip;
- Go to directory of /usr/share/sip/PyQt4 and paste (eg. /usr/share/sip/PyQt4);
- Run again the command cofigure.py;

PS: You probaly downloaded this sip in other folder and need to move for the correct folder. In my case was in PyQt4.